# Creating hooks on woocommerce, finding hook_names

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on a website where I am using woocommerce but rather than have a shopping facility I'm trying to change the wording, whilst keeping all the functionality to be able to add products to the shopping cart but calling everything an enquiry, and call for quote in replace for prices.

I have set prices so that when 0 is entered it won't display the standard 'Free!' and instead it states 'Call for quote' by adding this to my functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_cart_button_text' );    // 2.1 +

function woo_custom_cart_button_text() {

return __( 'Add to Enquiry', 'woocommerce' );

}
```

This works fine, and i sourced this particular hook online to obtain the code, however now I am starting to get further into the project I am wanting to edit more than just button texts.

My question is, how do you know where to obtain the hook names so I can start to create my own hooks for this, can they be seen from the class names when inspecting on google devtools? Dragging the woocommerce folder over into Sublime Text 2 and conducting a search for woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text I can be returned with reults to be able to see that hook, but how do you come across the hook name to begin with?
I have looked at http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html but couldn't see any names in relation to the above hook to begin trying to decipher how or where it was obtained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how do you know where to obtain the hook names so I can start to
>   create my own hooks for this, can they be seen from the class names
>   when inspecting on google devtools?

No.

To find a particular hook, you'd need to look at the [code base](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce). In repositories that are well organised such as WooCommerce, you should generally have a rough idea where to look for a particular hook.

For example, if I wanted hook in to the thankyou page I would probably first try looking in templates > checkout > thankyou.php. There I would find the `woocommerce_thankyou` action hook which would let me insert my custom functionality.

Alternatively, there's the [WooCommerce hook documentation](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks/).